# java: I closed the window on netbeans output/variables/breakpoints and i want it back

Tags: java, netbeans

When I was writing my program I accidentally closed the pane that shows output/variable watch/breakpoints etc. How can I get this back?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check out the view and search for it there.

Comment: I did but I cannot find it. I don't know what it's called so i don't know what I should be looking for. All I did was drag and resize my code so I could see it better the small output window disappeared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Watches` and `Variables` and so on, use `Window -> Debugging -> Watches / Variables / ...` and for `Output` use `Window -> Output`.

Alternatively use `Alt` + `Shift` + `1` / `2` / `...` for `Watches` / `Variables` / `...` and `Ctrl` + `4` for `Output`.